# How to display tooltip when InputText is Read Only?

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an input text field should be read-only.
I have added some description of the component in shortDesc property
I am using following code.

```
<af:inputText label="Office Code and Name"   
value="#{pageFlowScope.officeCode} - #{fn:substring(pageFlowScope.officeName,0,18)}"
 id="it2" shortDesc="#{pageFlowScope.officeCode} - #{pageFlowScope.officeName}" >
```

The tooltip text is not displayed.

How to display the tool-tip

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I tried your case, first I tried the read only input text with tooltip, like this:

```
                <af:inputText id="test" columns="60" simple="true" rows="2"
                            autoSubmit="true" immediate="true"
                            readOnly="true"
                            value="test text"
                            shortDesc="just to test the tooltip"/>
```

Well the tooltip won't show up when you set the inputText readOnly. Actually this is how ADF define the inputText behavior. So it's not your code's problem.

Then I'm thinking the readOnly inputText actually behaves like the outputText, so can you use the outputText instead? Because the outputText can show the tooltip: (and outputText is readOnly naturally)

```
                <af:outputText id="test"
                            value="test text"
                            shortDesc="just to test the tooltip"/>
```

Now you can see the tooltip when hover above the text. :)

Hope this helps~

Feel free to leave a comment if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a client listener on change event and add a tool tip using JavaScript to that component.